# Is there a way to create a 3D cylinder of the canvas element in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, 3d

I'd like to present the canvas as a cylindrical cone, which you can spin like a wheel in both directions. Is this at all possible with JS/CSS3?

Comment: Is canvas an element or shape...??

Comment: Like a a div really. Say I have the following setup:
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
And I want to show the full height, but curve it like this: http://www.learner.org/interactives/geometry/images/area_cyln_01.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML-Canvas is in the actual state only 2D, but the [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/) framework seems to be a pretty good solution for 3d-rendering within the canvas-element.

Comment: Thanks, I've been considering ThreeJS, but I wanted to know if there was some way to do this in CSS3 using the 3D transform methods.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at this new CSS3 feature: the **Custom filters / CSS shaders**.

Here are some really nice presentations made which describe the whole thing better than I could do (how to enable it on Chrome, how to start, how it works, etc):

- [HTML5rocks.com - Introduction to Custom Filters (aka CSS Shaders)](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/03/Introduction-to-Custom-Filters-aka-CSS-Shaders) by Paul Lewis ([@aerotwist](https://twitter.com/aerotwist))
- [Alteredqualia.com - Getting started with CSS custom filters](http://alteredqualia.com/css-shaders/article/) by [@alteredq](https://twitter.com/alteredq)

Basically, if you're already familiar with shaders and CSS3 transforms, it's all done...

#### Advantages

- WebGl-like GPU/3D acceleration
- JS-free (*only* GL shaders and CSS)
- Possibility to combine it with CSS3-transitions

#### Inconvenients

- New feature / Only supported by recent versions of *some* browsers (sometimes protected by a flag)
- Independant files for the shaders (unsure about that - maybe it's somehow possible to inline them in the html page like with WebGL)
- While implementing the example described below, I ran into a strange behavior: if the size of the canvas *(not the CSS size but the "JS" one, defining the pixels density)* gets too big, the shaders doesn't seem to be applied anymore, regardless of the operations you are doing or not on your canvas. I'm quite curious why, so I will try to investigate that.

---

### Example

To answer your more-precise requirements (canvas as a cylindrical cone), I made this small example: http://aldream.net/various/css-shader-demo/cylindricalConeTransformDemo.html. Hover above the canvas to make it wrap into a cone.

It doesn't spin, I just applied a simple transition effect I took from one example in the articles given above, but you should get the idea.

The vertex shader and fragment shader used can be found here:

- ["ConeTransform" vertex-shader](http://aldream.net/various/css-shader-demo/cylindricalConeTransform.vs)

  - Computes the wrapping into a cone and the 3D transformation of the canvas.
- ["ConeTransform" fragment-shader](http://aldream.net/various/css-shader-demo/cylindricalConeTransform.fs)

  - Does almost nothing. Just allows to display the unmodified DOM texture (the content of the canvas).

#### Simplified & commented Code

- **CSS**

```
    canvas {
        /* ... Prettify it as you wish */

        width: 640px;
        height: 560px;

        -webkit-filter: custom(url(cylindricalConeTransform.vs) /* Vertex-shader */
            mix(url(cylindricalConeTransform.fs) normal source-atop /* Fragment-shader and color-mixing properties */),
            36 2 /* Numbers of vertices */,
            /* Passing the values to the shaders uniforms: */
            amount 0,
            cylinderRadius 0.35,
            cylinderLength 250,
            transform rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg));

        -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter linear 1s; /* Transition on the filter for animation. */

    }

    canvas:hover {
        /* Same as above, but with different values for some uniforms. With the CSS-transition, those values will be tweened. */
        filter: custom(url(cylindricalConeTransform.vs) mix(url(cylindricalConeTransform.fs) normal source-atop), 36 2,
            amount 1,
            cylinderRadius 0.35,
            cylinderLength 250,
            transform rotateY(60deg) rotateX(60deg));
    }
```

- **Vertex-Shader**

```
precision mediump float;

// Built-in attributes
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

// Built-in uniforms
uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;

// Uniforms passed in from CSS
uniform float amount;
uniform float cylinderRadius;
uniform float cylinderLength;
uniform mat4 transform;

// Constants
const float PI = 3.1415;

// Cone function
vec3 computeCylindricalConePosition( vec2 uv, float r, float l ) {
    vec3 p;
    float fi = uv.x * PI * 2.0;

    p.x = r * cos( fi ) * uv.y;
    p.y = r * sin( fi ) * uv.y;
    p.z = (uv.y - 0.5) * l;
    return p;
}

// Main
void main() {
    vec4 position = a_position;

    // Map plane to cone using UV coordinates
    vec3 cone = computeCylindricalConePosition( a_texCoord, cylinderRadius, cylinderLength );

    // Blend plane and cone
    position.xyz = mix( position.xyz, cone, amount );

    // Set vertex position
    gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * transform * position;
}
```

- **Fragment-Shader**

```
/** spec: css */
precision mediump float;

void main() {
    css_ColorMatrix = mat4(
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    );
}
```

- **HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ... your meta, css, ...
<body>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <script>
        // Draw what you want in your canvas.
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** I'm actually not sure if you're asking for a cone or a cylinder, but the difference is small here. If you want the 2nd, you modify the *computeCylindricalConePosition()* function in the vertex-shader, evaluating p.x and p.y like this instead:

```
p.x = r * cos( fi ) /* * uv.y */;
p.y = r * sin( fi ) /* * uv.y */;
```

---

I hope it helps. I will try to develop my answer once I clarify some points.