# CSS3 Custom Filters applied to a canvas - Working only if strange conditions are met

Tags: css, canvas, 3d, shader

To answer the question [Is there a way to create a 3D cylinder of the canvas element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433384/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-3d-cylinder-of-the-canvas-element-in-css), I played around with the new **CSS custom filters**, trying to **apply them to a canvas** element.

It worked, but **only if some conditions I don't understand are met**. They seem linked to the *surface* defined by the `.height` and `.width` properties of the canvas. I first thought it was all about performance or interferences between the CSS painting and the canvas painting, but some experiments I made seemed to prove these theories wrong.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSx9s/2/) to illustrate this behavior (hover above the canvas to animate it - make sure custom filters are available in your browser).

Here are some observations I made using the demo:

- If *(`.height` x `.width` < 65760px)*

  - No problem, the filter is applied, whatever we are doing with the canvas.
- If *(`.height` x `.width` > 65760px)*

  - The filter doesn't seem to be applied anymore if we keep drawing in the canvas every frame.
  - Actually, even if we draw only once, it won't work.
  - But if we keep the canvas blank/cleared, then everything work fine *(well, we're thus simply applying a filter to a transparent DOM element)*.
- The CSS size (`canvas { width: ...; height: ...}`) of the canvas doesn't seem to affect it, neither does the number of vertices for the filter.

<s>I haven't been able to check yet if the value of *65760px* is the same on different PC</s> Tried on 2 different computers and got the same behavior / limit. I use Chrome Canary.

Any explanations?

Thanks in advance!

Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: CSS Custom Filters has been removed from all major browsers and has no plans for future development.**

Old answer:

The CSS Custom Filters implementation in Chromium does not yet support accelerated layers (e.g. videos, accelerated canvas). The feature is still undergoing a lot of development and changes.

In your example, it appears that the canvas is a non-accelerated layer below the size you mention. In this case, Custom Filters apply correctly on the layer.

When the canvas grows beyond a certain size, the browser promotes it to an accelerated layer, and Custom Filters don't yet work on accelerated layers.

In Chrome Canary, switch on the "Composited render layer borders" flag in about:flags and you can see the Canvas being promoted to an accelerated layer as you move the size slider up.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Updated the answer-- CSS Custom Filters is gone from all major browsers.

Comment: @Max That's such a shame! It was a really cool idea, too.... For some reason some demos appear to work in the current version of chrome, but not all the time.