# How to flip webpage like a book

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple webpage with 4 different page. On home page there is a navigation link of each page like -

Page1
page2
Page3
Page4

So now I want to implement something like if I will click on any link it should open that page like we flip pages of a book with some transition effects. So how can achieve this by using html5 or css3 etc?

Comment: Yes with html5, css3 or JavaScript

Comment: we are not here to make complete codes for you. but take a look at this http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/

Answer (score 6):

As it has been said, your question lacks a bit of former *investigation* to get some concrete answers, but here are some insights which can maybe help you:

## *Flip* transform

---

#### Using CSS3 2D transforms and clipping

- See the example made by Román Cortés: http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css3-page-flip-effect/ (Only works with Chrome - the demo is quite old, when only this browser was handling those CSS properties, with the `webkit-` prefix)
- The superposition of `div` with different z-index and the use of CSS3 **2D translation/rotation transforms** (with adapted origins) do most of the trick here. `box-shadow' and 'gradient' are added to simulate depth. The method by Hakim El Hattab, presented by nlob, is a kind of variant using the canvas to draw the *flip* instead.
- Advantages:

  - Light + Compatible with IE9+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 25+,...
  - The example shows both the front and back of the pages
- Inconvenient:

  - A bit flat...

#### Using CSS3 custom filters

- See the example in Adobe's FilterLab: http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/customfilters/cssfilterlab/ ('Add Filter' > 'Custom' > 'page-curl' - Only works with Firefox Aurora and properly-set Chrome Canary - ie by enabling "CSS Shaders" in 'about:flags')
- The trick here is to use a quite new CSS3 feature, the **custom shaders**, which allow you to apply webGL-like shaders to your DOM elements (A nice introduction to those notions here: [HTML5rocks.com - Introduction to Custom Filters (aka CSS Shaders)](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/03/Introduction-to-Custom-Filters-aka-CSS-Shaders) by Paul Lewis). You can find many resources to implement the shaders. For instance:

  - [Deforming Pages of 3D Electronic Books](http://www2.parc.com/istl/groups/uir/publications/items/UIR-2004-10-Hong-DeformingPages.pdf) - *Paper by Lichan Hong, Stuart K. Card, and Jindong (JD) Chen*
  - [Adobe's *page-curl* shader](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Demo-for-National-Geographic-Forest-Giant/blob/master/phonegap/assets/shaders/page-curl.vs) - *Github*
- Advantages:

  - Real 3D rendering, with possibility to change the point of view, the lighting, ...
- Inconvenient:

  - New technology - currently only compatible with Firefox Aurora and Chrome Canary + some restrictions to the DOM elements (see an example in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484347/css3-custom-filters-applied-to-a-canvas-working-only-if-strange-conditions-are))

## Animation & Interface

---

All those solutions use the CSS `transition` to create the animation, by tweening the properties of the 2D transforms or the input attributes of the shaders.

The animation can be triggered by a basic CSS state (`:hover` for instance) or through Javascript, by handling the chosen event (click, drag, ...). You can for example use this handler to set the classes of your DOM element to trigger the transition:

- CSS:

```css
.page {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 1s;
}
.curled-page {
    transform: translate(42px, 42px) rotate(42deg);
}
```

- JS:

```js
document.getElementById('page1-corner').onclick = function() {
    var page1 = document.getElementById('page1');
    page1.className += ' curled-page'; // Supposing page1 already has "page" as class.
};
```

---

If you dig a bit in all the given answers, you should be able to find your way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you need to have understanding of following properties in css and basic javascript events.

preserve 3d,
transform origin,
transform rotate,
z-index.

And you cannot use hyperlinks for navigation as reloading the page would conflict your requirement of flipeffect.Nobody will be providing you the entire script for your task.you have to do it yourself.